# Make post from graph api so it return following error : An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, post

I want to share post from graph api in python

```
import requests
import urllib


host = "https://graph.facebook.com"
path = "/oauth/access_token"
params = urllib.urlencode({"client_id":"XXXXXXX","client_secret": 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','grant_type': 'client_credentials'})

url = "{host}{path}?{params}".format(host=host, path=path, params=params)

r = requests.get(url)
print "r",r


payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'client_secret': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}
file = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?', params = payload)    
result = file.text.split("=")[1]
print "result",result


param = {'client_id':'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'access_token':result}
file_one = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token_info?', params = param)
print "access token info file",file_one
print "access token info file.text",file_one.text


host = "https://graph.facebook.com"
path = "/me/feed"
params = urllib.urlencode({"message":"Hello, World.","access_token": file.text.split("=")[1]})
url = "{host}{path}?{params}".format(host=host, path=path, params=params)
r = requests.post(url)
print "value of r",r
print "r.text",r.text
```

i get token but when i try to post in fb so it return error like

> {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"G3PcKSN1mFA"}}

in facebook three types of tokens 1)user token 2)app tokens 3)page token but i required usertoken from above script i get app token not user token can you please give solution fo how we get user token

Comment: That looks like you are just using your app access token - that can’t be used with `/me`. If you want to post as the user, then you first of all have to make the user log in and grant your app posting permission.

Comment: @CBroe can you please explain how we can give posting permission

Comment: By asking for it during login. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: any another way without login

Comment: Why? If you want other users to use your app, you need to implement login anyway.

Comment: i awnt user access token currently i get app token do you know how i get user access token

Comment: By implementing login ...

Comment: can you plz help for how we implement login from python script ?

Comment: Yes: You start by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i found my solution from get app-access token and then convert them in to user access token this link is useful for me

[Facebook Graph API: Have app access token, need user access token without interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291085/facebook-graph-api-have-app-access-token-need-user-access-token-without-intera)